# Emacs Alignment - Force region to left justify at cursor

Tags: emacs, alignment

I have an emacs Major/Minor mode which handles alot of automatic indentation, spacing etc via fill-region and other commands.  Mostly this works, but there are times when I'd like to select a region, and force the region to simply left justify each new line at the first cursor.

So, for example, the indentation provided by the major mode for certain rare instances erroneously looks like this:

```
@{Returns a new @racket[list?] without the
            @racket[last] of @racket[lst].
            @examples[#:eval the-eval (remove-last '(1 2 3 4 5))]}
```

I want to highlight that region and make it look like this:

```
@{Returns a new @racket[list?] without the
@racket[last] of @racket[lst].
@examples[#:eval the-eval (remove-last '(1 2 3 4 5))]}
```

All of the alignment, align-regexp attempts I've tried havent worked.  It seems like this should be a simple enough desire, and may it's the major mode that's interfering here?

Thanks.

Comment: What does "at the first cursor" mean? At the same level of indentation as the first line of the region?

Comment: Yes, assuming the cursor is highlighting the start of the region.

Comment: Yes, my cursor is already at the first character of the first line since I'm selecting the region, so I'm ok with using that character as the alignment target for all the remaining lines in the region.

Comment: Oh I see. You just meant the same column as either point or mark (whichever is earliest in the buffer? or whichever is left-most in its line?).

Answer (score -1):

The easiest function I found out is [evil mode](http://wikemacs.org/index.php/Evil)'s `evil-shift-left`. It is bound to `<` in evil mode, but you can call the function without using the mode:

```
;; install the mode, prebuilt in emacs24
(require 'evil)
;; define your key binding
```

and then highlight the region and call M-x evil-shift-left

Hope that suits your needs.

Comment: That shifts the entire region left, it doesn't align all secondary lines to the beginning of the starting line, as in my example.  Also, requiring a 60MB library for one function seems like overkill.

Comment: You said you will highlight a region: so do not highlight the first line. As for the dependency, I know, but it isn't much trouble with computers nowadays so I would do it if that suits my needs.